# Tried to install Windows, and now can not boot Ubuntu partitions - Error Loading Operating System

Tags: boot-failure

i have one hard disk and two operating systems Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

I wanted to install Windows XP also but i had only two partitions.

I used GPARTED to resize partition with Lubuntu to get more space for new partition. After that i rebooted and wanted to install XP on new partition. But I could not choose that new partition, also i tried to delete it and create again, i didn't touch partition with Ubuntu and Lubuntu. As this didn't work i couldn't choose this partition i decided to restart and see if i did mistake somewhere in GPARTED. But after restart i get "Error loading operating system".

Seems like i made mistakes in this process. Now if someone can help me solve this? I would be happy if is possible at last backup my data from Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question is *slightly* unclear. Please clarify it, and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: I will try explain better and in short.

Comment: I will try explain better and in short. I had 2 partitions, one is with Ubuntu and another one is with Lubuntu. I made smaller partition with Lubuntu to get more space for new partition for XP. After restart i get this error. I didn't write here anything new but i hope that is more understandable. Let me know if i need explain something better.  Seems like here enter is not new row

Comment: You never actually told us what error you got.

Comment: After reboot when bios is loaded i get error loading operating system

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try installing XP using VirtualBox, which is a free program from Oracle to create virtual machines, into which you can install XP just like normal, but run it without exiting Ubuntu.  It works well, and can be made to look exactly like the separate XP.

But if you want to install it on your drive, make sure you create a Primary Partition, as it will not work on a logical drive.  Also you will find that after installing XP, Ubuntu will no longer be accessible, and you will need to restore GRUB in the boot sector after XP over-writes it with its own boot sector code.  Using VirtualBox will not have this problem.

After you make space, you need to select the empty space, and create a new partition (primary) using ntfs.  If you can't choose primary, then you must be inside a secondary partition.  When that happens, you need to pay attention to the list below the graphical representation, and shrink the extended partition, which is a container around the logical drives.

Comment: I am using VB for XP but now i need to have it separate for some applications, also i don't prefer wine. Seems that i did something wrong in this process, can you explain me or give me link how i restore GRUB in my case?

Comment: Here's a guide that should help:  [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to back up your data,you can try the following steps:

1. start your laptop with a live-CD or USB(recommended) that is set-up with Startup Disk Creator
2. Click on 'Try Ubuntu'
3. once logged in, open a folder
4. Click on the partitions from where you want to backup your data (partitions can be found on the left hand side of the screen.
5. Connect an external hard drive or USB for backing up data
6. Copy and paste you files.

You can reinstall Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Windows XP after that.

Tip: Install Windows XP first

(assuming that you want to install the operating systems alongside each other and not in a virtual machine)

Comment: Thank you for tip, i will definitely backup in that way if i don't find solution for recover.

Answer (score 0):

if you tried to install windows onto the spare partition then I take it you would have booted off the Windows disk and started the install program?  The Windows installer will install it's own bootloader over the top of grub in the MBR (Windows likes to think it's the only operating system on the planet so you lose the ability to boot Ubuntu).

The question on how to re-install grub and get access to your Ubuntu and Lubuntu installations has already been adequately [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

The problem of getting Windows XP installed on your machine is probably a matter of getting the very first primary partition free and available for install. Again, Windows likes to think it's got full controll of the hard drive.  You should be able to move your partitions up to leave the first primary partition free.  After installing XP you will have to repair the grub bootloader again because Windows will overwrite it again.